# jQuery ready() issues - $(this) not usable and code applies only to one element

Tags: jquery, document-ready

Im having issues with getting some jQuery to run when the DOM is ready.

I have two forms, each with a `<select>` which when my code runs should load in other form elements.

When the user first loads the page, I want these selects on `ready()` to grab certain attributes (form action, `load()` target etc) and then load that in. Works perfectly fine when using `change()` and I can get one `<select>` to work when but not both.

### HTML

```html
<form action="php/bagCreate/newBag_bag.php" method="post" id="form1">
  <select id="target" data-target="upForm" class="get" name="bagLevel">
    <option>1</option>   
    <option>2</option>  
    <option>3</option>   
  </select>        
</form>

<form action="php/bagCreate/storeItems_bag.php" method="post" id="form2">      
  <select id="target2" data-target="upFormType" class="get" name="itemName">
    <option>A</option>   
    <option>B</option>  
    <option>C</option>   
  </select>        
</form>
```

### JS

This works for a single form, but the second wont load

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select.get').ready(function() {
    var action = $('select.get').parent().attr('action');
    var target = $('select.get').data('target');
    $('#'+target).load(action, $('select.get').parent().serializeArray());     
});
```

changing `select.get` to `this` inside the ready function causes neither of the forms to load.

Using `change()` works perfectly fine for both forms, although it is a bit of a repetition

```js
$('select.get').change(function() {        
  var action = $(this).parent().attr('action');  
  var target = $(this).data('target');  
  $('#'+target).load(action, $(this).parent().serializeArray());      
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `.ready()` on anything other than the `document`, anything else doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's right, the document is only ready ONCE.

Comment: Did you check what `this` is inside you callback? Because the truth is, `.ready` completely ignores which elements are selected.

Comment: From the [**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) -> "The `.ready()` method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just trigger the change event on pageload ?

```
$('select.get').change(function() {        
  var action = $(this).parent().attr('action');  
  var target = $(this).data('target');  
  $('#'+target).load(action, $(this).parent().serializeArray());      
}).change(); //trigger it on pageload as well ...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine, even removed the `ready()` one as well, a lot cleaner. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to apply your code to more than one `select` element in the jQuery object. Also, as the comments suggest, the `ready()` method should be reserved to the `document` object.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.get').each(function(i) {
        var action = $(this).parent().attr('action');
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $('#'+target).load(action, $(this).parent().serializeArray());
    });
});
```

Note how in each iteration of the `each()` *callback* function, `$(this)` refers to the <sub>i</sub>th element in the `$('select.get')` object.

Comment: This worked along with adeneo's solution, although I went with his due to it removing the code repetition. Also helped me with my misunderstanding of `ready()`. Thank You

Comment: @KieranFJ No problem. I prefer adeneo's solution as well, since in this case you're already binding a handler function to the elements so it makes sense to just trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

Should your first code snippet read as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.get').each(function() {
        var action = $('select.get').parent().attr('action');
        var target = $('select.get').data('target');
        $('#'+target).load(action, $('select.get').parent().serializeArray());     
    }
);
```

Changing the ready method to the each method would run the defined function once for each element found with the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select.get').each(function(){
        var $t = $(this);
        var $p = $t.parent();
        var action = $p.attr('action');
        var target = $t.data('target');
        $('#'+target).load(action, $p.serializeArray());
    });
});
```